# CSS alignment across all browsers

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, google-chrome, alignment

I'm running into problems aligning an input text field, password text field and login button across all browsers.  If it works on one browser, it doesn't work on another.  Any work around?

How it works in **Google Chrome:**

```
header #login_button
{
    padding: 8px;
    border-radius: 0px 6px 6px 0px;
    float: right;
    margin-top: 2px;
}

header input[type=submit]
{
    border: none;
    border-radius: 3px;
    padding: 4px 8px;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 10px;
}
```

How it works in **Internet Explorer**

```
header #login_button
{
    padding: 9px;
    border-radius: 0px 6px 6px 0px;
    float: right;
}

header input[type=submit]
{
    border: none;
    border-radius: 3px;
    padding: 4px 8px;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 9px;
}
```

And how it works in **Firefox**

```
header #login_button
{
    padding: 7px;
    border-radius: 0px 6px 6px 0px;
    float: right;
}

header input[type=submit]
{
    border: none;
    border-radius: 3px;
    padding: 4px 8px;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 9px;
}
```

Just to sum up the differences:

**Chrome requires:**

```
font-size:10px;
padding: 8px;
margin-top: 2px;
```

**Firefox requires:**

```
font-size: 9px;
padding: 7px;
```

**IE requires:**

```
font-size: 9px;
padding: 9px;
```

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: You are using some css reset though, right? In case you aren't, please do.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you need to write different styles for different browsers. You can use something like `normalize.css` or `reset.css` from anyone of the following. These CSS files have necessary styling and hacks to make your html look almost exactly the same in all browsers.

http://necolas.github.com/normalize.css/

http://www.cssreset.com/

Hope that helps.

Answer (score -2):

You should use like this :

i forgot to mention , Copy and paste the line below, inside  and  tag
then `.webkit` will work

```
 <pre>
    <script src="http://github.com/rafaelp/css_browser_selector/raw/master/css_browser_selector.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    </pre>
```

```
header input[type=submit]{
    font-size: 10px; /* standard */
    font-size: 10px\9 /* IE 8 and below*/ 
    padding: 9px\9; /* IE 8 and below */
    *padding: 15px\9; /* IE 7 and below */
    _padding: 16px\9; /* IE 6 */
}
```

**For chrome :**

```
.webkit header input[type=submit] {
  font-size: 10px; 
  padding: 8px;
  margin-top: 2px;
}
```

[Reference Link](http://rafael.adm.br/css_browser_selector/)

Comment: IMO, it makes life hard, while using soo many CSS browser hacks, especially for maintainability.

Comment: For some reason, .webkit doesn't work.  I reset my cache as well.  I'm going to try to IE hack right now.

Comment: And no, I am not using css reset.  I'll look into it.  That may be the problem.

IE hack works perfectly